# Uploading a File to Server in Intel XDK when server requires authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, appframework, intel-xdk

I am developing an app using [Intel XDK New](http://xdk-software.intel.com/). The issue I am having involves the Intel XDK JavaScript Bridge API, in particular the [uploadToServer method](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493213).

I have written a simple server backend using C# MVC4. I have working code for uploading a photo taken from a mobile device, but the code fails when I make the upload url on the server require authentication.

I am uncertain how MVC authentication works exactly, I think it uses a mix of cookies and some http headers? To clarify I am using [MVC Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs). However, the server doesn't really use forms, or return views. I have modified the authentication required event to just return a 404 instead of a view.

The real question is, does anyone familiar with the Intel XDK know if it is possible for the uploadToServer method to also pass the authentication cookies/headers/however it works? So far all my requests to the server have used the [intel appframework $.ajax method](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api2/index.html#%24_ajax). (Not jQuery it just looks like it). This seems to pass the authentication stuff as I have methods on the server to return Json that require authentication and it all works fine.

**My server code:**

```
[HandleError]
[MyAuthorizeAttribute]
public class PhotosController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult UploadPhoto()
    {
        Log.Write("UploadPhoto");
        if (Request != null && Request.Files != null && Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                if (Request.Files[fileName] == null || Request.Files[fileName].ContentType != "image/jpeg") 
                    continue;

                Request.Files[fileName].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/photo.jpg"));
            }
            return Json("File(s) Uploaded", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json("No File(s) to Upload", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**My JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.file.upload.busy", function(evt) { $('#afui').popup("Sorry, a file is already being uploaded"); });
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.file.upload",UploadComplete);
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.file.upload.cancel", function(evt) { $('#afui').popup("File upload was cancelled "+evt.localURL); });

function MyUploadMethod() {    
    intel.xdk.file.uploadToServer(pictureURL,"http://mywebsite.co.uk/Photos/UploadPhoto", "", "image/jpeg", "UpdateUploadProgress");
}

function UpdateUploadProgress(bytesSent,totalBytes)
{
   if(totalBytes>0) {
        currentProgress=(bytesSent/totalBytes)*100;
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML=currentProgress+"%";
        console.log(currentProgress);
   }           
}

function UploadComplete(evt)
{
    if(evt.success===true)
    {
        $('#afui').popup("Success");
    }
    else {
        $('#afui').popup("Error uploading file "+evt.message);
    }
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="";
}
```

Comment: You are using the [MyAuthorizeAttribute]. Every request send a cookie named ASPXAUTH that will tell to the server about the identity of the client request. If the request doesn't has this cookie, your attribute will block the request. I'm not familiar with this Intel framework, but you should find out how to send cookie or change your authorization attribute to read some token from the request and authorize this kind of request.

Answer (score 0):

well i think you should try, I had use it for my previous project which uses CORS technology.

Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");